# Handlebars template are not updated during compilation in .build folder

Tags: templates, handlebars.js, nestjs, aws-serverless

### Situation

I'm currently developing a serverless project which renders some HTML (.hbs templates) with NestJS and Handlebars.

1. When I first run `nest build && sls offline start`, I can test my app endpoints in offline mode with *postman* => the templates are rendered perfectly.
2. But if I now update something inside a **.hbs template** and then `stop/restart` the offline server, my template changes are not taking in account when I test my endpoints (**it is like my template are compiled only once**).
3. If I change something in a **.css file** and then `stop/restart` the offline server, the compiled files seem to be overrided as expected and I can see the new CSS in the rendered templates.

Currently, I have to **delete the .build/ folder** and then `stop/restart` the offline server to see my template changes in the rendered HTML when I test my endpoints...

### How can I avoid this workaround ?

**I would like my compiled templates to be at least updated when I just `stop/restart` the offline server.**
And the *best* solution would be to update the compiled templates *"in watch mode"* but I've read somewhere that templates are only compiled once when the server starts (https://github.com/nest-modules/mailer/issues/42)
Here is my nest-cli.json conf:

```
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "assets": ["**/*.hbs"],
    "watchAssets": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's not the best solution, but I solved similar problem this way:
I wrote gulp task, which watches .hbs files and imitates change of main.ts file.

```
function watchHandlebars() {
  watch('src/views/**/*.hbs').on('all', () => {
    console.log('Restarting Nest');
    const path = './src/main.ts';
    fs.utimesSync(path, new Date(), new Date());
  });
}
```

Comment: I think it i not ideal but this works fine though. I accept your answer, thank you ! This is the guld task I created : ```task('hbs', function watchHandlebars() {
  watch('src/templates/**/*.hbs').on('all', () => {
    console.log('Update Handlebar templates');
    src('./src/templates/**/*.hbs').pipe(dest('./.build/src/templates'));
  });
});```