# Nest js disable .hbs files cache

Tags: handlebars.js, nestjs, express-handlebars

I am using `NestJS`(based on Express) with `Handlebars` template engine.
When I am changing `.hbs` files and refreshing a page, the `NestJS` still renders the old versions of templates, until recompilation/relaunch.

I don't know exactly, but I think, `NestJS` somehow caches `.hbs` templates.
I tried to add `.hbs` files as assets in `nest-cli.json` file, but that didn't solve the problem.

So, how to disable the cache?

Thanks.

Comment: I run in the same issue and I am interested if you found a solution. This is the topic I posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70152366/handlebars-template-are-not-updated-during-compilation-in-build-folder

Comment: @TCH I will answer under your question